# In VB6, should I prefer sqr() or ()^0.5?

Tags: vb6

I am doing some numerical analysis work in VB6, and the question arises of which of

```
sqr(x)
```

or

```
x^0.5
```

I should use.

Is there any difference in the method used to evaluate these two expressions, and if so, which of them should I prefer?

Comment: @Peter: Actually, the square root function *is* named SQR() in VB6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB6 does not document the method is uses to evaluate sqr() or x^0.5. Empirically, sqr() is much faster, which could mean that they are using a dedicated root finding algorithm here. The use of a specialized algorithm *could* mean that sqr() also has better numerical stability, but I have no information regarding this.